# Has ttk time limit passed? Ps3 -ps4

Tags: destiny

I just bought the ps4... I bought the legendary edition and expansion pack on the ps3. But for some reason I can't pass it over to the ps4... The answer is probably right in front of me. But I'd rather be sure. I've spent at least 140$ already on ps3

Ps. I DiD it on November or whenever it came out

Answer (score 1):

Quote:

> DESTINY: THE TAKEN KING IS NOT ELIGIBLE FOR THE DIGITAL UPGRADE PROGRAM

Source: https://www.bungie.net/en/help/article/12122

The limited-time upgrade offer for Destiny only applied to expansion pass holders, Expansion 1 (The Dark Below), and Expansion 2 (House of Wolves).

The first two expansions may still be available for free, but ideally you'd purchase the Legendary Edition again on PS4 anyway, granting you complete access to the game's current content-- The expansion price tag alone is almost the cost of the entire bundle. If you're not sure if you're entitled to the expansion, you can borrow/rent a PS4 disc of the game and check "related content" on your PS4. If your expansions have a price tag next to them, they need to be purchased.

You may also log into the PlayStation Store to see what expansions you are entitled to.

https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-us/search/f=%5Edestiny%7Cbucket~games